# ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: datepicker, angular-material, angular5, angular-calendar

I have used `mat-date-picker` inside my application, the html file looks like this :

```
  <mat-form-field>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date" placeholder="Choose a date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

I have used the exact same piece of code in my another component and it works, but in this component it displays the error:

> ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

Even though the page is loading after the error, the button of date picker doesnot get displayed and i cannot select a date.

Comment: Where is the closing Tag for `<mat-form-field>`? I mean something like that: `</mat-form-field>` and check if you have the `[formGroup]="form"` in your opening tag for form etc. Could you post the part of `*.component.ts` for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you've imported the module `MatInputModule`.

Comment: @k.vincent - can you add your comment to the original question instead of my answer?

Comment: Sure… Done. Was a mistake.